# Uninitialized Usage in libstdc++ filesystem?

Tags: c++, libstdc++, std-filesystem

Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <filesystem>

int main() {
    std::filesystem::path p{"/"};
}
```

When compiling with clang10 with the flags `-std=c++17 -fsanitize=memory -g -O1 -stdlib=libstdc++` it compiles totally fine, but when running, the memory sanitizer finds the following error:

```
==166467==WARNING: MemorySanitizer: use-of-uninitialized-value
    #0 0x560e38eafc41 in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__detail::operator<<<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&>(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::__detail::_Quoted_string<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char> const&) /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.1.0/../../../../include/c++/10.1.0/bits/quoted_string.h:124:32
    #1 0x560e38eaf03c in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::filesystem::__cxx11::operator<<<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::filesystem::__cxx11::path const&) /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.1.0/../../../../include/c++/10.1.0/bits/fs_path.h:441:7
    #2 0x560e38eaecdb in main ~/test/test.cpp:15:15
    #3 0x7f5d0fa58001 in __libc_start_main (/usr/lib/libc.so.6+0x27001)
    #4 0x560e38e3033d in _start (~/test/a.out+0x2133d)

SUMMARY: MemorySanitizer: use-of-uninitialized-value /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.1.0/../../../../include/c++/10.1.0/bits/quoted_string.h:124:32 in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__detail::operator<<<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&>(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::__detail::_Quoted_string<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char> const&)
Exiting
```

When compiling with `-stdlib=libc++` it works completely fine. See also [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/-myPde) (sadly, the msan-output is a bit non-descriptive there).

Is the memory sanitizer a overzealous or is there something wrong? I looked briefly into the offending file and the code

```
    for (auto __c : __str._M_string)
      {
        if (__c == __str._M_delim || __c == __str._M_escape) // <- line 124
          __ostr << __str._M_escape;
        __ostr << __c;
      }
```

seems ok to me (`__str` is of type `std::__detail::_Quoted_string<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&` that only has one user defined constructor, that value initializes all three members from parameters).

Output of `clang++ -v`:

```
clang version 10.0.0 
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.1.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.1.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.1.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.1.0
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.1.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Candidate multilib: 32;@m32
Selected multilib: .;@m64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a false positive.

You should report it as a Sanitizer bug; it appears to be similar to [issue 1238](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/1238).

Comment: Thanks, I did just that.